# Is it possible to have nested tic() and toc() in Julia as in Matlab? If not what is the way around it?

Tags: matlab, time, timer, julia

Is it possible to call nested tic() and toc()  in Julia?
The problem is that I cannot send the name of timer I select to toc() function.

Something like this in Matlab (I am quoting from Matlab help)

`

```
REPS = 1000;   minTime = Inf;   nsum = 10;
tic;  % TIC, pair 1

for i=1:REPS
   tStart = tic;  % TIC, pair 2  
   total = 0;
   for j=1:nsum 
      total = total + besselj(j,REPS);
   end

   tElapsed = toc(tStart);  % TOC, pair 2  
   minTime = min(tElapsed, minTime);
end
averageTime = toc/REPS;  % TOC, pair 1  `
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you can, let me know if this isn't what you mean by nesting `tic` and `toc`.

```
tic()
sleep(1)
tic()
sleep(1)
toc() # elapsed time: 1 second
sleep(1)
toc() #elapsed time: 3 seconds
```

Also, if you want to time something in Julia, it can be a lot easier to use the `@time` macro, which also keeps track of memory allocation.

```
@time (sleep(1); @time sleep(1);)
# elapsed time: 1 second, 672 bytes allocated
# elapsed time: 2.13 seconds, 6 MB allocated
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like there's a predefined function for using the return value of `tic` yet. You can write your own using the `time_ns` function.

```
function toc(t0)
  t1 = time_ns()
  t = (t1 - t0) / 1e9
  println("elapsed time: ", t, " seconds")
  return t
end
```

Comment: The current answer does not help unfortunately to solve the problem.

Comment: @user25004 I added some more, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes Thanks. time_ns() was the function that I did not know about :-)

Comment: It is interesting that the value returned by such a toc function, does not match the value return by the original toc function.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the timing macros `@time` and `@eleapsed` can be used with a block argument if you need to time more than one line.

```
@time begin
    do_something()
    do_something_more()
end
```

But as the runtime semantics of Julia strongly favors functions and local variables, it is usually best to wrap code blocs in a function, instead of running it in global scope.